# AngularJS directive not firing (partial views and .remove())

Tags: angularjs

My main overview page has a few partial views in it (that run on different links). Each of these partial views has an element that refers to a directive (expander).

My problem is if I go to a partial view that has that directive, and then go back to the main screen and to a different partial view, the directive won't run on the newest screen.

The partials are loaded with ajax calls, and removed using .remove() on the parent in the view.

I'm not sure where the problem would be, so here are some bits of code that might be relevant.

My expander directive:

```
angular.module("toolkit").directive("expander", ['$timeout',  function($timeout)
{
  function determine(scope, heightValue) {        
    if (scope.isExpanded) collapse(heightValue);
    else expand(heightValue);
  }

  function expand(heightValue) {
      //does expanding things
  }

  function collapse(heightValue) {
      //does collapsing things
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        var height = 0;
        scope.$watch(attrs.expanderHeight, function (value) {
            height = value;
        });

        $timeout(
            function () {
                $(elm[0]).on('click', function () {
                    scope.$apply(determine(scope, height));
                });
            }
        )
    }
  };
}]);
```

Html for partial views (they all have this same thing):

```
<div class="acct-sum round-a accordion-top">
    <div expander expander-height="170" class="title">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Irrelevant things here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This directive runs in every partial view as long as its the first I go to. But after switching back from one view to another, it stops working. I've put breakpoints into it and it never hits it at all.

Any ideas? I can post more code if anyone will find it relevant.

Edit:

The partial views are loaded on click like so:

```
// Bind account summary links to load the accountHistory partial view.
$(".view-history").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hide();

    var acctId = $(this).data("account");
    var t = $("#body_content_wrapper");
    t.append("<div class='progress' />");


    // load the template from the server in lue of client-routing
    util.load({
        viewId: "accounthistory",
        target: t,
        action: util.config.baseUri + "accountHistory",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: $(this).data("account") }
    })
    .complete(function (html) {
        $(".progress").remove();

        util.publish("telnot.views.showAccountHistory", { account: acctId });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think the problem lies with `remove` calls. Not only do they remove the element from the DOM, but they also strip any bound events, which is perhaps why you're not seeing behaviour re-run (nb. If you're using jQuery with Angular, try `detach` instead of `remove`).

Comment: Thats where I think the problem is to, I just can't figure it out. Using detach doesn't help. Is there a way to re-bind the directive or something?

Comment: Ah, I should've asked if there's a reason you're binding to a click inside a `$timeout` instead of using bind directly (i.e. `elm.bind('click', ...)`). Posting how you attach the partial view containing your `expander` directive might help with suggestions too.

Comment: The timeout is there so this will only run after the rest of the page has loaded because there is a bunch of things that need to load.

Comment: Interesting, so you're using jQuery's `load` to rope in your partials. Again another hunch, but `load` might be caching your partials, which could be stopping it from re-running your directive code. Try disabling caching, otherwise you could try force your partial to be recompiled using the `$compile` service.

Comment: Ooh I found the problem. In another area, the partial view is $compiled (so it runs the first time), but that $compile statement is in a if statement (that is always false after the first run). I'll have to refactor some things to fix it, but thank you for your help! Your mentioning $compile made me look for it :)